# Create a colored bar plot using pandas by grouping using multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have the following Pandas code.

```
import pandas as pd
DATA=pd.DataFrame({'Sex': ["M", "M", "F", "F","F","F","M"], 'Support': ['N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N',"Y","Y","N"]})
data=DATA.groupby(['Support','Sex']).size().plot(kind='bar')
```

I want it to output bar plot like the following
[image]

Notice that there are two groups: "No" and "Yes" and the bars have no spaces in between them. Finally colored. My code produces spaces and nasty x-labels. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
from operator import methodcaller

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# replace the letters with words
df = df.replace({"M": "Male", "F": "Female", "N": "No", "Y": "Yes"})

# turn df into desired format for groups
table = df.pivot_table(index="Support", columns="Sex", aggfunc="size")

# real plotting
fig_size = (16, 9)
ax = table.plot(kind="bar", figsize=fig_size)

# sort the rectangles (bars) from left to right
rectangles_sorted = sorted(ax.patches, key=methodcaller("get_x"))

# flatten the table to form labels later on
flattened_table = list(table.stack().to_dict().items())

# alternating colors of bars
colors = ["red", "blue"]

# for each rectangle...
for j, rectangle in enumerate(rectangles_sorted):
    # choose a color & set it
    color = colors[j % 2]
    rectangle.set_color(color)
    
    # generate a label
    (support, gender), val = flattened_table[j]
    label = f"{gender}\n{val}"

    # put the label on the plot
    r_width = rectangle.get_width()
    r_height = rectangle.get_height()
    r_xpos = rectangle.get_x() 
    ax.text(r_xpos + r_width / 2, r_height + 0.01, label,
            ha="center", va="bottom", size=20)
    
# some aesthetics
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), size=20, rotation=0)
ax.set_xlabel("")
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.legend(fontsize=20)

plt.box(False)
```

I get:

[image]

Comment: your code is good and will use it thanks a lot. However is there no inbuilt function in pandas to give the same result without much coding?

Comment: @MafeniAlpha I'm afraid not, but I'm not sure.. Actually, `df.pivot_table(index="Support", columns="Sex", aggfunc="size").plot(kind="bar")` is the real plotting part. But customized coloring and putting text on the plot will, I think, inevitably take some lines of code and pandas' plotting isn't directly addressing that.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the plotting with plotly.express.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px #pip install plotly

DATA=pd.DataFrame({'Sex': ["M", "M", "F", "F","F","F","M"], 'Support': ['N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N',"Y","Y","N"]})
DATA['COUNT'] = 1

#Creating a DataFrame with count info for plot
df_plot = pd.DataFrame(columns = ('Sex', 'Support', 'Count'))
idx = 0
sex_dic = {} #save which sex you already counted
for sex in DATA.Sex:
    if sex in sex_dic:
        pass
    elif sex not in sex_dic:
        sex_dic[sex] = 'counted'
        #filter the uncounted Sex
        df_step = DATA.set_index('Sex').filter(like = sex, axis = 0) 
        support_dic = {} #save wihch stat you already counted
        for stat in DATA.Support:
            if stat in support_dic:
                pass
            if stat not in support_dic:
                support_dic[stat] = 'counted'
                #filter the uncounted stat for the uncounted sex
                
                df_step2 = df_step.set_index('Support').filter(like = stat, axis = 0)

                #Here I add the new row to the DataFrame created for plotting
                df_plot.loc[idx] = [sex, stat, len(df_step2)] #the lenght of the double filtered df is the number of times the combination [SEX,STAT] appears, i.e., the height of the each bar
                idx += 1

df_plot.replace({'M':'Male', 'F':'Female'}, inplace = True) #Just set the text for each color

#plotting with plotly.express is pretty easy. Just say you want bars colered by SEX, arranged by SUPPORT.
fig = px.bar(df_plot, x = df_plot.Support, y = df_plot.Count, color = df_plot.Sex, barmode = 'group') #barmode = 'group' is to make different colors appear side by side
fig.update_layout(xaxis = dict(tickvals = ['Y', 'N'], ticktext = ['Yes', 'No'])) #update the xaxis so the text show YES and NO
fig.write_html('answer.html') #save as an interactive html, of which you can save a png.
```

[image: snippet of .html]